# A good keyboard macro program for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, macros

I'm looking for a good keyboard macro program for Ubuntu Linux?
 I want to easily be able to "start recording" have it record all keys pressed. Then when I stop recording save it. then I want to be able to call the macro by hitting a special key and selecting the sequence. having to open a text file and program the macro will create too much overhead.

Comment: This question was on topic when written, and should be preserved for historical reasons. Just as an update, a new tool xdotool is a very good answer to this question.

Answer (score 10):

The program that comes closest to this that I know of is [**XMacro**](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/):

> The XMacro package contains two simple, C++ programs (xmacrorec and xmacroplay) for recording and replaying keyboard and mouse events on an X server.

This is available in the Ubuntu repository as the **xmacro** package.

Comment: After `sudo apt-get install -y xmacro`, go to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts and create e.g. F9 as `timeout 120 bash -c 'notify-send "Recording macro; press ESC to stop" ; xmacrorec2 -k 9 > /tmp/macro ; notify-send "Recording macro finished; use F10 to play it"'` and F10 as `bash -c 'notify-send "Playing back macro on $DISPLAY" ; xmacroplay "$DISPLAY" < /tmp/macro'`. Now you can record with F9, stop with ESC and playback with F10. It stops after 120s (in case you forget it).

Comment: @Mark your comment deserves a separate answer linked to this one. We could then upvote it could be properly formatted

Comment: @BorisPavlović Added it to this answer since it's a follow-up on it.

Answer (score 6):

autokeys is a good option though it is more heavy weight than i am looking for